# How to move programmatically tool buttons to right toolbar area?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would like to have the tool icons at the right side, rather than at the top. As I experienced, I can move them manually, I can set their `orientation()` to vertical, but they remain at the top; I can set `setAllowedAreas()` which means I restrict where the toolbar areas can reside, but the tool buttons reside at the top. I need something like `setToolbarArea()`. Is there something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `addToolBar` again to move the toolbar.

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBar),

> If the main window already manages toolbar then it will only move the
>   toolbar to area.

I.e.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QToolBar * toolBar;

public slots:
    void moveLeft();
    void moveRight();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    toolBar= new QToolBar("Tool Bar");

    toolBar->addAction(QIcon(":/qt.png"), "FirstAction", this, SLOT(moveLeft()));
    toolBar->addAction(QIcon(":/qt.png"), "SecondAction", this, SLOT(moveRight()));

    addToolBar(Qt::RightToolBarArea, toolBar);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::moveLeft()
{
    addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, toolBar);
}

void MainWindow::moveRight()
{
    addToolBar(Qt::RightToolBarArea, toolBar);
}
```